# How does LOESS work in STL Decomposition Algorithm?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, decomposition, sql

I am trying to write a SQL program to calculate STL Decomposition of monthly time series data. In going through the algorithm in the [original paper](http://www.nniiem.ru/file/news/2016/stl-statistical-model.pdf), inner loop step 2 has the detrended series grouped by sub cycle (in my case groups of months) to which LOESS smoothing is applied to produce estimated values for the data set + 6 months on either side.

How does one apply Loess to sub-series groups and produce the required estimated series?

Comment: Implementing STL decomposition in SQL appears to be extremely difficult to me. Why don't you use a statistical software like R to do the calculation?

Comment: Part the challenge, part limitations of the system I am working with.

Comment: Section 2 of the original paper explains how loess smoothing is calculated. It consists of weighted polynomial regression repeated many times.